# How do I make my buttons work correctly? (Kivy in python)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm pretty new to programming and can't find any solution to my current problem. I am building a language learning app in python using the kivy framework. I have a section with full phrases that works like duolingo. This means that for each phrase in Chinese, buttons containing words from the English translation would spawn and when clicked, the word from the button would be added to a label above. Similarly, when clicking the label, the word would delete itself from the label and return back to the screen as a button. My problem occurs when I have a phrase that contains two of the same word. When I click both buttons for that word, the words get added to the label without any problem. However, when I click the label to make them return as buttons, only one does so correctly. The other word disappears and its button is left disabled. How could I solve this issue?

Here is my current code where I tried to resolve this issue unsuccessfully. Note that the whole quiz part of the app is handled by the following class:

```
class HSK1GrammarScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HSK1GrammarScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.background_color = background_color

        self.grammar = self.load_grammar("hsk1_grammar.json")

        self.buttons_dict = {}

        self.load_new_grammar()

    def load_new_grammar(self, instance=None):
        self.clear_widgets()

        close_button = Button(text="X", size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 50), pos_hint={'x': None, 'y': None},
                              pos=(0, self.height - 50), background_color=button_color, color=text_color)
        close_button.bind(on_press=self.close_hsk1_grammar)

        self.add_widget(close_button)

        # Randomly select a phrase
        self.random_phrase = random.choice(self.grammar[0]["phrases"])

        # Create and add a combined label for Chinese and Pinyin
        combined_label = Label(
            text=f"{self.random_phrase['example_phrase']}\n\n({self.random_phrase['pinyin_phrase']})",
            font_name="NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.ttf",
            font_size=30,
            color=text_color
        )

        self.add_widget(combined_label)

        answer_label = Label(text="",
                             font_name="NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.ttf",
                             font_size=20,
                             color=text_color
                             )

        self.answer_label = answer_label

        self.add_widget(answer_label)

        answer_label.bind(on_touch_down=self.label_touch_down)

        words_list = self.random_phrase["translation"].split()
        random.shuffle(words_list)

        # Create a BoxLayout for the buttons
        self.buttons_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10, padding=20)  # Adjust spacing as needed
        print("Button Layout Width Before Adding Buttons:", self.buttons_layout.width)  # Debug print
        self.add_widget(self.buttons_layout)

        # Create buttons for each English word
        for word in words_list:
            button = Button(
                text=word,
                on_press=lambda btn, w=word: self.check_button(w),
                background_color=button_color,
                color=text_color,
                size_hint_x=None,
                size=(len(word) * 20, 50)
            )
            print(f"Button Width: {button.width}")
            self.buttons_layout.add_widget(button)
            self.buttons_dict[word] = button  # Store reference in the dictionary

        print("Button Layout Width After Adding Buttons:", self.buttons_layout.width)  # Debug print

        submit_button = Button(
            text="Submit",
            background_color=button_color,
            color=text_color,
        )

        submit_button.bind(on_press=self.submit_answer)

        self.add_widget(submit_button)

        print("Main Layout Width After Adding Widgets:", self.width)  # Debug print

    def label_touch_down(self, instance, touch):
        if instance.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            # Get the word from the label text
            selected_word = instance.text.split()[-1]

            # Remove the last word from the label text
            instance.text = ' '.join(instance.text.split()[:-1])

            # Find the button with the same text and make it visible again
            button = self.buttons_dict.get(selected_word)
            if button:
                print(f"Label Touch Down - Setting button text: {selected_word}")
                button.text = selected_word  # Set the text back to the button
                button.disabled = False  # Enable the button to make it visible

    def check_button(self, selected_word):
        current_text = self.answer_label.text
        if current_text:
            current_text += " " + selected_word
        else:
            current_text = selected_word

        self.answer_label.text = current_text

        # Find the pressed button and update its text
        found_button = False
        for child in self.buttons_layout.children:
            if isinstance(child, Button) and child.text == selected_word:
                if not found_button:
                    print(f"Check Button - Clearing button text: {selected_word}")
                    child.text = ""  # Clear the button text
                    child.disabled = True  # Disable the button to prevent further clicks
                    found_button = True

    def submit_answer(self, instance):
        submitted_answer = self.answer_label.text.strip()

        if submitted_answer == self.random_phrase["translation"]:
            print("Correct!")
            self.load_new_grammar()
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")

            # Reset the answer_label
            self.answer_label.text = ""

            # Restore original buttons
            for word, button in self.buttons_dict.items():
                button.text = word
                button.disabled = False

    def close_hsk1_grammar(self, instance):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(MainMenu())

    @staticmethod
    def load_grammar(file_path="hsk1_grammar.json"):
        try:
            with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                data = json.load(file)
            return data
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Error: File '{file_path}' not found.")
            return []
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print(f"Error: Unable to decode JSON from '{file_path}'.")
            return []
```